# Сравнение Vector3 [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d, сравнение, операторы, векторы

Моя запись:

```
Vector3 ROTACCEL = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
if(!Input.GetKey("q") && ROTACCEL > new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0)){...}
```

является ошибочной, ведь оператор `>` невозможно использовать при сравнении Vector3.Что в этом случае можно использовать?

Comment: чтобы сравнивать вектора на `>, <, ==` - для начала надо знать что это будет значить. Вот по-твоему что значит когда один вектор больше другого?

Comment: Когда все значения ROTACCEL больше чем 0.1f, 0, 0

Comment: То есть даже если у `ROTACCEL` например значение `x` и `y` будет равно `99999999999999999999999`, а `z` будет `-0.0000000000000000009`, то значит он будет меньше? интересно

Comment: Будет больше, по большинству.x1 > x2, y1 > y2, z1 < z2

Comment: по какому большинству?  
То есть если у `ROTACCEL` например значение `x` будет равно `99999999999999999999999`, а `y` и `z` будет `-0.0000000000000000009`, то значит он будет меньше?

Comment: Именно.Именно так и будет, ведь х больше, а у и z-меньше.

Comment: А почему такая логика? Чем `x` хуже или лучше, чем `z` например? почему логика не `x1 < x2, y1 > y2, z1 > z2` или `x1 > x2, y1 < y2, z1 > z2` ?  и почему на логику влияет именно количество параметров со слегка превышающим значения других, а не сами эти значения? разве `99999999999999999999999`  не превышает  те же два нуля остальных значений?

Comment: Логика такова: если в первом векторе например х и у больше чем во втором, значит первый вектор больше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68615/discussion-between-jetfly-and--).

Answer (score 0):

### Решил.

Написал вместо

```
Vector3 ROTACCEL = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
if(!Input.GetKey("q") && ROTACCEL > new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0)){...}
```

это:

```
Vector3 ROTACCEL = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
if(!Input.GetKey("q") && ROTACCEL.x > 0.1f){...}
```

(мне нужно было сравнить только х, но полное сравнение тоже не мешает.)

Comment: Можно сравнить длину: `ROTACCEL.magnitude > 0.1f` Или `sqrMagnitude`, чтоб не извлекать корень лишний раз

Comment: Да и это работает, теперь другая проблема